# ¿Cómo hacer una expresión regular no sensible a acentos?

Tags: javascript, regular, expresion

Tengo una variable simple de cadena:

```
 var saludo="Hola, ¿Cómo estás?";
```

Ahora deseo detectar si se encuentra la palabra "ola" sin importar combinación de mayúsculas o minúsculas. Lo logro fácil usando una expresión regular:

```
saludo.match(/olA/gi)
```

Ahora ¿Qué pasa si deseo detectar la palabra "como" sin importar combinación de mayúsculas o minúsculas o las letrás acentuadas? Lo siguiente no sirve:

```
 saludo.match(/CoMO/gi)
```

Entonces ¿Como se logra crear una expresión regular que de una palabra "sin acentos" pueda encontrar en una frase con acentos la primera? Es decir en este caso la palabra "como" si existe aunque tiene una diferencia con la mayúscula y además la "o" está acentuada.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta sería *no se puede*. Doy algunas alternativas y más abajo una explicación un poco más detallada del por qué:

Para buscar una palabra, si se tiene claro que palabra es y qué letra puede estar acentuada, se puede usar un grupo con ambas letras (en este caso usando la palabra *cómo*):

```
/c(o|ó)mo/gi
```

Para buscar cualquier combinación de letras se podría hacer algo cómo:

```
/[A-zÁ-ÿ]/gi
```

Y en navegadores modernos algo así:

```
/\p{L}/giu
```

En este último caso hacemos uso de la clase `\p` y la bandera `/u` para buscar cualquier cáracter con categoría "Letra" (Letter) en Unicode (https://es.javascript.info/regexp-unicode#propiedades-unicode-p)

> **Tip:** En el caso que se quiera encontrar la primera aparición solo se debe remover la bandera `/g`, en tal caso quedaría: `/c(o|ó)mo/i`. Y en el caso que se quiera distinguir entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, se debe remover la `/i`, quedando `/c(o|ó)mo/g`. Más info sobre banderas: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#b%C3%BAsqueda_avanzada_con_banderas

**¿Y por qué *no se puede*?**

Básicamente está relacionado a la definición de las cadenas de caracteres (Strings) en JavaScript. Una string en el fondo es una secuencia de enteros que se interpreta como UTF-16 (Unicode), y, para éste estándar **o** y **ó** son dos caracteres distintos, y, cómo las expresiones regulares por definición son patrones que comparan cadenas de caracteres, es correcto que no coincidan.

Más información:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16
https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type

Y una herramienta útil para probar expresiones regulares:

https://regexr.com/